# Get data from specific sheets in google sheet and extract specific columns from it using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to get specific column data out of specific sheets in one big google sheet.
For example, I have a list of sheets

```
Sheets = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3']
```

and from these sheets, I want to retrieve specific columns like

```
Column_headers = ['A', 'B']
```

What I am doing right now is getting the data from

```
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

sa = gspread.service_account(filename='file.json')
book = sa.open("book")
Sheets = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3']
Column_headers = ['A', 'B']

for i in Sheets:
    2022_sheet = book.worksheet(i)
    records = 2022_sheet.get_all_records()
    data_2022 = zip(*(e for e in zip(*record) if e[0] in Column_headers))
    getdata_2022 = pd.DataFrame(data_2022, columns = Column_headers)
    print(getdata_2022)
```

I am getting the following error

```
GSpreadException: the given 'expected_headers' are not uniques
```

that is because the headers are not unique (obv) that's why I am retrieving specific columns, also I can't understand the bit where I loop through the 'Sheets' to get the data only from specific sheets. Eventually the end result should be two columns 'A' and 'B' with all the data from the specific 3 sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC try doing the following:

```
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd
import pandas as pd

# connect to the service account
sa = gspread.service_account(filename='file.json')

# open the Google Sheet
book = sa.open('book')

# The list of sheet names and columns that you want
Sheets = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3']
Column_headers = ['A', 'B']

# list comprehension using gd.get_as_dataframe 
# to create a list of DataFrames for each sheet
# then you concat all frames together into one DataFrame
df = pd.concat([gd.get_as_dataframe(book.worksheet(sheet))[Column_headers]
                for sheet in Sheets])
```

You may need to filter out `NaNs` if you have empty rows in your Google Sheet. Something like:

```
df = df[~df.isna().all(axis=1)]
```

## update

replace `df = pd.concat([gd.get_as_dataframe(book.worksheet(sheet))[Column_headers] for sheet in Sheets])` with the following

```
dfs = []
for sheet in Sheets:
    df = gd.get_as_dataframe(book.worksheet(sheet))
    try:
        df = df[Column_headers]
    except KeyError:
        df = df[['A']]
        df['B'] = np.nan
    # the commented out code below will add the sheet name to each frame
    # df['Sheet_Name'] = sheet
    # you can also remove all nan rows here if you need
    # df = df[~df.isna().all(axis=1)]
    dfs.append(df)
    
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: This is AMAZING! thank you for that. There are some sheets where column B would not be available is there a way we could add null values in that column? Right now it throws an error if it doesn't find column B in sheet 3. (I know it's a totally different question)

Comment: Sure, in that case we will need to do a traditional for-loop with a try, except. I will update the answer.

Comment: @hyeri see if the update works for your needs.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for this, just one issue I am facing, if I add column B here df = df[['A','B']] as the column is present in some of the sheets. It throws error index not found but if I take it out it prints null values even for those sheets where this column is populated

Comment: I have tweaked the code a bit using reindexing 'df = df.reindex(Column_headers,fill_value= np.nan, axis=1'). Seems to be working for now. Many thanks for the help again. :)